# How Redis commands are internally implemented by Redisson?

Tags: redis, apache-storm, distributed-computing, jedis, redisson

I was exploring redisson and decided to use for the ease of its simplicity when compared to Jedis, and few other good reviews i found over internet.

The environment on which i will be using redisson is Storm topologies.

> It's not a good idea to create threads by application level code in a
>   Storm Topology

I dig deeper to some extent of redisson code which internally translates the commands to async and command executor and promise.

just want to confirm . Is redisson internally spawning threads to achieve this.

A follow up. Is Jedis also doing the same in its internal implementation. 
Please consider pipeline implementation also in your answers

Answer (score 0):

Redisson mentions in some perf documentation I found somewhere that Redisson v.x supports on the order 30k threads/sec.   I read this as concurrent requests.

I imagine at least two of those are in separate threads

Not sure what you are asking, but perhaps this gives some insight

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping